# Imagemagick: saving animated gif working on Windows but not Ubuntu

Tags: php, windows, ubuntu, imagemagick, imagick

I'm using ImageMagick and Imagick to process images. I am using both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 as testing environments. At the moment, I'm trying to process animated .gif images. In Windows, the animation is saved and works without a problem, but in Ubuntu, the image only saves the first frame. It's saving as a .gif image, but not animated.

ImageMagick and Imagick are my preferred image processing libraries over GD, and I've done quite a bit of work with them in the past; so I'm pretty familiar with how they work. I know that "writeImages()" in Windows only works with an absolute path, but it works with either relative or absolute in Ubuntu.

I'm not really interested in using the command line exec php functions, I'd rather use the Imagick library.

I've run out of ideas. Has anyone else run into a similar problem? I've been working on this for about a week. Am I missing something glaringly obvious, or have I found a bug?

Here is the function:

```
// Re-sizes images //
function resize($file_src) {
    try {
        // Set bigger time limit for bigger gifs //
        set_time_limit(180);
        // Original Image //
        $image = new Imagick($file_src);
        // Destination to save to //
        $destination = dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'images' . DS . basename($file_src);
        // Set the re-size values //
        $size_w = 250;
        $size_h = 250;
        // Separate the frames //
        $images = $image->coalesceImages();
        // Loop through each frame and resize //
        foreach ($images as $frame) {
            $frame->thumbnailImage($size_w, $size_h);
        }
        // Save the images to a single file //
        $images->writeImages($destination, true);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

// Image in base dir //
$image = 'original.gif';

// resize image and send to image dir //
resize($image);
```

In Windows, my ImageMagick version is:

```
convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.1-8 2013-01-02 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib freetype jp2 jpeg lcms lzma ps tiff x xml zlib
```

In Ubuntu, the version is:

```
convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.7-0 2013-10-11 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: zlib
```

Edit:

I ended up submitting a bug report to Imagick on github. I rewrote the function to work on the command line, and it worked flawlessly. Here is the rewritten function if anyone is interested.

```
<?php

function resize_cmd($file_src) {
    set_time_limit(180);
    $destination = dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'images' . DS . basename($file_src);
    $w = 250;
    $h = 250;

    exec("convert {$file_src} -coalesce -resize {$h}x{$w} {$destination}", $output);

    if (!empty($output)) {
        echo $output;
    }
}

?>
```

[Here](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/issues/20) is the bug I reported.

Comment: Works for me™. Do you have a sample image it doesn't work for?

Comment: @Danack It works on Windows, just not Ubuntu, here is the image I've been working with [3.gif](http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/3.gif)

Comment: Well that image works for me on Centos with apparently the same version of Image Magick.

Comment: Yeah, it's got me banging my head off the walls. I don't know what it could be. I thought that perhaps it was some kind of permission error i was missing, but I'm not getting any errors at all.

Comment: Ok - so what you need to do now is, test it via the command line with just Image Magick. If it's still a problem, report it to Image magick. If it only happens when you use Imagick report it to https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick

Comment: @Danack That worked, should have been pretty obvious from the get go. Thank you for showing me where to report the bug to the imagick team.